# IHttpActionResult returns result with brackets and escape slash , why is this happening

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

While **I could use C# to replace** the [\ and ]  I do not know why they are even appearing.

**I Call a Web API service from within a C# application**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:11974/");  
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/GetNTIDWithEmail/"+ responseModel.ReferredToNTID + "/");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var x = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

}
```

**x = "[\"SPRUCEK\"]"**

Why does it have the brackets and backslash?

**The Web Api that I call looks like this**

```
[Route("GetNTIDWithEmail/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetNtidfromEmail(string id)
{
    var query = (from c in _db.rEmails
                    where c.Email.Contains(id)
                select c.ALIAS_NAME);


    return Ok(query);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking at it in the debugger.  The debugger is escaping the quotes, so the string really looks like:

```
["SPRUCEK"]
```

which makes sense.  You're returning an `IEnumerable<string>`, which in JSON will be an array.  You're getting one result back, so the JSON looks on point for what you're returning.

Judging from your method name, I bet you only want one result.  If that's the case, try:

```
 var result = (from c in _db.rEmails
                where c.Email.Contains(id)
            select c.ALIAS_NAME)
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: ok, so with adding in FirstOrDefault that does get rid of the brackets , but whether I mouse over the variable 'x'  or see the output in vs immediate window it is showing    "\"SPRUCEK\""   I want to take the variable value and assign to a string property and save to the database table so isn't it going to be a problem?

Comment: Sometimes I do indeed want JSON , as I do a lot of my calls to web api with jquery ajax,  but I figured in this situation that I just wanted to have my c# web app. inside a c# method simply call up this other web api service inside c# instead of from the client with javascript .

Comment: Well the problem is that it then inserts and stores the double quotes into the database table   "SPRUCEK"     , so how do I prevent that?